# Limit one userID to a specific date in table

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i am currently working on a school assignment.

I need to make a database that registers school students and their sport events. But with a twist:

One student can only have one event per day. But there can be multiple different students on each day.

I have made the date a primary key since my teacher said that was the solution, but it isn't.
Now i can plan one event on a date, and nothing else on that date.

This is my database:
[image: Database]

This is my first time asking a question about mysql so please correct me if i'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Just form a composite unique key on those columns

Comment: Can you maybe give me a bit more context on this one?

Comment: For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, it might help a little bit if the column names are in English.